# Javascript - transform `elem.style.left` into integer?

Tags: javascript

I need to make this comparison:

```
if (x < siteA.style.left || x > siteA.style.left + land.width() ) {
```

however siteA.style.left returns 20px (e.g) so the condition doesn't work. How do I remove the px and transform it into an integer so I can work with it?

I tried `alert(parseInt(siteA.style.left))` and it returned NaN however `alert(siteA.style.left)` returned 30px, 60px etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: I forgot to say, I tried `alert(parseInt(siteA.style.left))` and it returned NaN.

Comment: In this case `siteA.style.left` is probably not defined

Comment: Just tried `parseInt('20px')` in Firebug console, works as expected. Your object is probably undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var leftPos = parseInt(siteA.style.left, 10);
```

where `10` is the base, good practice to always specify it.

Comment: I forgot to say, I tried `alert(parseInt(siteA.style.left))` and it returned NaN.

Comment: @Liso22: Try adding the base of 10 like i have done in my answer eg `alert(parseInt(siteA.style.left, 10))`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var left = parseInt(siteA.style.left.replace('px', ''), 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery you can use `$('#siteA').offset().left` which returns only the integer value.